# Updating ListView after deleting MySQL Data

Tags: android, android-listview

Here is the delete call in my context menu:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        int clickedPosition = info.position;
        tvInt = reviews.get(clickedPosition);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Delete:

            new DeleteCommentTask().execute();

            reviews.remove(clickedPosition);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Review Deleted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;

        }
        return false;

    }
```

I do verify that in my DeleteCommentTask it does remove the comment from my database.  But ListView not being updated?

**UPDATE:
Here is my adapter I am using:**

```
            MyReviewObject co = new MyReviewObject[reviews.size()];
            int index = 0;

            for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String i : reviews) {
                co[index] = new MyReviewObject(datelist.get(index),
                        reviews.get(index), items.get(index),
                        cats.get(index));
                index++;
            }

            adapter = new MyReviewAdapter(getActivity(), co);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I guess `DeleteCommentTask` is a separate thread? call `reviews.remove(clickedPosition);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after the execution of youe delete thread.

Comment: the problem is, then clickedPosition is out of scope if I call it in the PostExecute of my AsyncTask

Comment: then pass the position in your `DeleteCommentTask's constructor`..

Comment: ok, I did it, didn't work.  I am thinking that what I am removing in the List is not working?

Comment: Update:  I have verified that "ClickedPosition" is correct.  The adapter is just not refreshing.

Comment: "reviews" is the arrayList? And it same as it is used in your `Adapter`?

Comment: Ok,  I see what may be issue based on what you said.  See updated code on my adapter.  `reviews` is just one of three lists in the `ListView`.

Comment: you need to remove/delete item in `co` array. That is not possible/recommended, use `ArrayList` of "MyReviewObject" in Adapter. btw any good reason to use an array?

Comment: Yes, ArrayList seems to be the way to go. No reason; someone on Stack Overflow originally recommended before it became more complex to how it is now.

Answer (score 1):

See the updated answer

Don't do this

reviews.remove(clickedPosition);

Just remove the comment from the data source from where it was getting used in the
getView of adapter. say from a Arraylist of Strings.

After this only notifying the adapter will going to do the trick

Try executing this code in the onPostExecute of DeleteCommentTask

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Review Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Try Passing Argument to the Execute method of DeleteCommentTask which will notify which position to remove.

Comment: Didn't work.  Can anyone verify that `reviews.remove(clickedPosition);` is the appropriate way to remove the item from my list?

Comment: I have updated my question to show you the type of adapter I am using.  I think I was wrong to try to just remove `reviews` which is just part of the adapter data.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because of this:  "*you need to remove/delete item in co array. That is not possible/recommended, use `ArrayList` of "MyReviewObject" in Adapter.*"

I need to use an `ArrayList` which can shrink dynamically, an Array can't.  Also, I was just removing a single String `ArrayList`.  Inside my `Array` object are multiple ArrayList's.  **So I should be removing the entire object instead**.